# 100% opacity UILabel over a 50% opacity background (UIView?)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, user-interface, uilabel

So right now I have a `UIView` with a `UILabel` in it. I want the background to have an opacity < 1.0 and the label to have an opacity of 1.0. However since alphas propagate down the view hierarchy, the label ends up with an opacity < 1.0 as well.

Is there anyway to do what I want without making the `UILabel` a subview of another view??

Comment: Why don't u want to add another view? I think this should be the right way.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Just set the background color to be semitransparent:

```
view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
```

Or, in Swift:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

Or, Swift 3:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

Note that, in this particular case, `UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)` is more concise, but `colorWithAlphaComponent` will work in general.

Comment: SWIFT: view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)

Answer (score 13):

Besides being available in code, you can do this quite easily from iB as well:

1. Within the storyboard, select the view you wish to edit;
2. From the right panel, make sure the Attributes inspector is opened;
3. Click on the right side of the "Background" drop down box and choose "Other ..."; it will open a colour picker dialog;
4. Change the "Opacity" at the bottom to set the background colour opacity.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color of the `UIView` with a semi-transparent color or make the image itself semi-transparent. This way it's a property of the view that is transparent, not the view itself.

Answer (score -5):

You can use this:

```
self.view.layer.opacity=0.5
```

Comment: This does not do what poster wants. This sets the opacity for the label text as well as the background.